# What's the difference between curling the data via cat and via data parameter?

Tags: curl, soap, http-post, httprequest, newline

If I `curl` a SOAP server via:

```
curl 'http://the-soap-server' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Action' -X POST \
--data '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tem:Booking>
    ...
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

I get an error response from the soap server. Yet weirdly, if I store that request in a file and issue the same request via:

```
cat stored.xml | curl 'http://the-soap-server' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Action' -X POST \
--data @-
```

it suddenly works. How are those curl request different?

Answer (score 0):

New lines.

I figured this out using a php proxy http server to see the proper request recieved and compared the difference.

The first approach keeps the newlines, the other one removes them. And this particular soap server does not like newlines.

So to get curl via inline data, one has to:

```
curl 'http://the-soap-server' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Action' -X POST \
--data '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:Booking>...</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'
```